# Animations not working with Emotion Library

Tags: reactjs, emotion

**Relevant code:**

```
const fadeInRight = keyframes`
    from {
        opacity:0;
        transform: translatex(-200px);
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
        transform: translatex(0);
    }
`;
const bubbleFadeRight = css`
  animation: ${fadeInRight} 2s infinite;
`;

//check condition and set bubbleFade = bubbleFadeLeft or bubbleFadeRight
const bubbleFade = { bubbleFadeRight };

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Not working: */}
      <div css={bubbleFade}>I blink!</div>

      {/* Working: */}
      <div
        css={css`
        // animation: ${bubbleFade}
      `}
      >
        I blink!
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Reproduction:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-rain-46ocm

**Problem description:**
I don't know why when I use case 2, it's working but case 1 is not woriking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not assigning the animation CSS attribute properly, you don't need to re-define your css attribute:

```
    ...
    <div
     css={css`
     // animation: ${bubbleFade}
     `}
    >
    ...
```

just assign it directly since you have `bubbleFadeLeft` and `bubbleFadeRight` as CSS variables

like this:

```
  ...
  <div css={bubbleFadeLeft}>Case 1: I blink but not working!</div>
  <div css={bubbleFadeRight}>Case 2: I blink!</div>
  ...
```

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-field-uhb0o)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I want to check condition and set bubbleFade = bubbleFadeLeft or bubbleFadeRight. After, use css={bubbleFade}. But it not working.

Comment: I updated my sandbox to check for condition, check it now https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-field-uhb0o I added two conditions for both animations.

Comment: thanks, I found my mistake, I set bubbleFade = { bubbleFadeRight }, but just only bubbleFade = bubbleFadeRight, curly braces is unnecessary.

Comment: yes, That's what I mentioned in my answer, glad it working now :)